# pre-loading .net DLLs - GAC, NGEN, LoadAssembly, & PrepareMethod

Tags: .net, load, lazy-initialization

We want to reduce the load time for bringing up Forms in our app. We have plenty of time in a worker thread to load the DLLs (mostly a ton of DevExpress DLLs) before a user will want one. I've read a number of posts here, on MSDN, etc. and have a couple of questions.

1. Most of the DLLs are in the GAC. I think (not sure) that NGEN is run on those DLLs either when installed or the first time used. Is that correct? If so, no need to call NGEN.
2. We have 2 DLLs that are not in the GAC, is there an example of how to call NGEN in a WIX script?
3. We still need to load them. Is [loading assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021613/how-to-pre-load-all-deployed-assemblies-for-an-appdomain) or [PrepareMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175743/pre-load-all-assemblies-jit) the better approach?
4. We are an Office AddIn (hence lots of time to load in a worker thread) and have one DLL (not in the GAC) that is loaded when Office starts. Is NGEN the only thing we can do to speed up loading that main DLL?
5. We also have a single not-managed C++ (shim) DLL that is also loaded when Office starts. Anything we can do to speed it up?

thanks - dave

Comment: If you could ask *one* question at a time, which of those 5 would you pick?

Comment: #3 - what is the best way to fully load and JIT the DLLs.