# ASP.NET MVC BuildManager.GetAssemblies()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, and on app start up I'm looking using BuildManager to get all referenced assemblies.I'm looking through all types in the application to find a few that I want (it's dynamic so I don't know what types I need until start up).

Essentially my code looks like this:

```
var allTypes = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                  .Cast<Assembly>()
                  .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());
```

I'm calling this on app startup but also at the beginning of each new request in order to dynamically find types.

So my questions are:

1. Since ASP.NET doesn't load assemblies until they're needed, by calling `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()` am I loading ALL assemblies before they're needed and causing a performance issue?
2. Is iterating through all types a bad idea for each request? I could cache the types but ASP.NET has the option of loading assemblies dynamically after I've cached them, right? If so I may miss some types which are indeed there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it every request: do cache as early as possible; reflection is slow.

Pre-load all the assemblies and do it on app-startup; I have a system that I use in a lot of our websites which has to do a lot of dynamic stuff based on deployed assemblies, and I do all the work on startup.

Yes startup is therefore slower - but that's less of a problem than each request taking longer.

You will then most likely be interested in a question I asked and answered a while ago about how to preload all deployed assemblies reliably: [How to pre-load all deployed assemblies for an AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021613/how-to-pre-load-all-deployed-assemblies-for-an-appdomain).

I still use the same process to this day and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! It seems as if `BuildManager.GetAllAssemblies()` loads everything - even dynamic assemblies. So if I iterate through that at start up and cache the results, would this effectively be "preloading" so I don't have to do it manually?

Comment: It would appear that for websites that is indeed the case, so yes you should be able to rely on that to get all the deployed assemblies for a website.  If you iterate them and start interrogating them then definitely yes it will pre-load them (to a point, the JIT will still only do in-memory compilation of what's needed, when it's needed).