# Dlls are not loaded in AppDomain when debugging Asp.Net project (the second time)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, dynamic-loading

I have a Project Reference (to `B.dll`) in Asp.Net MVC project, which is not used statically. At startup I'm looking through the loaded assemblies and dynamically register types from them in the IoC container.

When I rebuild MVC project and hit F5 I see `B.dll` in the list of loaded assemblies returned by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.

Then I hit Stop and F5 again. This time there's no `B.dll` in the loaded assemblies. However, if I call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("B")` it'll be loaded correctly.

If I rebuild the project cycle repeats.

So the questions are:

1. I assume, that dlls from `bin` folder should be loaded by IIS at startup, am I right?
2. Why Visual Studio behavior on first and 2nd debug sessions different? And most importantly, how to force it to loaded all the libraries on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. At first time, when compilation occurs.
2. Because those libraries will be loaded on demand, after they were compiled.

This should help [How to pre-load all deployed assemblies for an AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021613/how-to-pre-load-all-deployed-assemblies-for-an-appdomain)

Comment: thanks for clarification, the link provided looks exactly what I need, looking into it